# object has no method lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am trying to apply `lightbox` to my `div`.

I have jquery file and `lightbox.js` loaded but still getting Object has no method `lightBox` error message. I was wondering if someone can help me out on this one. Thanks a lot!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic/basic.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js'></script>
<scirpt type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){   

    $('#image img').lightBox();
})
</script>


<div id='image'>

/**/these images are generated from ajax call. not sure if it's relevant.**


<img src='a.jpg'/>
<img src='b.jpg'/>
<img src='c.jpg'/>


 </div>
```

Comment: i love people just give me -1 without telling me the reason.

Comment: How are you sure that `js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js` is loaded? If it's loaded, you should not get an error `object has no method lightBox`

Comment: @Juan I added in my html script. Are there other ways to test it?

Comment: use the inspector in your browser to see if the script is not loading, or try hitting the script's url directly

Comment: What happen with $('img').lightBox();? By the way, I think you must initialize lightbox after images are loaded, in ajax callback, try lightbox().init() (ro initialize(), start()... I do not know the correct syntax).

Answer (score 0):

In my case i found conflict between JQuery and $

changing document ready was the solution

```
 <script type='text/javascript'> 

    $(document).ready(function(){   

        $('#image img').lightBox(); }) 

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was ftp software, which did not properly upload the script. Try to copy/paste manually the source from the original file "jquery.lightbox-0.5.js" to your server.